# Converting the logic for cts:search to search:search

Tags: search, xquery, marklogic, cts-search

I have been working with `cts:search` in my project but somehow it feels the result time are taking a bit longer than expected. Can `search:search` help? If so, how?

For example I have the query as

```
let $query := cts:and-query((cts:element-value-query(xs:QName("Applicability"),"Yes")))
```

and I want to fetch the document URIs. I was using:

```
cts:search(collection("abc"), $query)
```

and it returned the URIs, but how can this be extracted using `search:search`?
Or is there something other than search can help for improving the execution time?

Comment: As a general note: search:search uses cts:search under the covers. cts:search and other cts functions are usually quicker, but more low-level.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you interested in retrieving the documents, or just the URIs?

If you are only looking to retrieve the URIs of the documents that have an element with that value, then use [`cts:uris()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts:uris) instead of `cts:search()`. The `cts:uris()` function runs unfiltered and will only return URIs from the lexicon, instead of retrieving all of the documents, which can be a lot more expensive than `cts:search` if you don't need the content.

```
cts:uris("", (), cts:and-query(( collection("abc"), $query)) )
```

When using `cts:search`, the first thing that I would try is to add the `unfiltered` option to your search and see if that helps.

By default `cts:search` executes filtered:

> A filtered search (the default). Filtered searches eliminate any false-positive matches and properly resolve cases where there are multiple candidate matches within the same fragment. Filtered search results fully satisfy the specified `cts:query`.

So, try executing the same query with the "unfiltered" option:

```
cts:search(collection("abc"), $query, "unfiltered")
```

You could also look to create [an index](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/admin/range_index) on that Applicability element, with either an element-range-index or a field-range-index, and then use the appropriate range-query instead of a value-query.

Comment: Thanks for your quick help!! I need content also but yes the unfiltered worked out for a better response time.Will try index creation also but need content hence cts:uris might not help much here ..!!